# CSS media screen and mobile issue

Tags: css, responsive

On my site, im using standard css to apply for everything, except

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
```

if my screen/browser is equal or lower than 480, it uses whatever thats under that media.

But my problem is that it dosent work on my iphone (iphone 5S).
I was able to find out that `@media (max-screen-width: 480px) {` would work, but then my browser width on 480 wont apply to it.

I have searched around different sites , but all i see of their entire css files, is that they only use `max-width`, and while vising their pages, it works great on my phone.

***Question: How can i easily do so it would apply for both browser and screen/mobile?***

Comment: Do you have this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13003491/1898563

Comment: Voted down because that was literally the first result on google: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=iphone+media+query+not+working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this indise your `head` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   // code goes here
}
```