# Website Design not displayed correctly only on iphone 4S

Tags: html, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I've created a web design which is working fine on every device except my client's Iphone 4S.
I've tested my website online on:
http://mobilewebtest.eu/iphone4
http://iphone4simulator.com/

I've tested hands-on mobiles also i.e. iPhone6/7/8.

All of the above testings were positive. I couldn't get hold on an iPhone 4S but the website is working on every other phone perfectly. Client says that he didn't open the website ever before so cache storage is out of question I think.

I've tried below solutions:

Solution 1:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Solution 2:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Solution 3 (Not tried):
Someone pointed something strange on this post:
[Responsive design - Media Query not working on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002731/responsive-design-media-query-not-working-on-iphone)

that adding a comment after DOCTYPE might fix the issue which doesn't seem that convincing to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This comment line needed for bootstrap to work on mobile devices -->
<html lang="en">
```

Looking forward for your great support

Comment: What do you mean by "not" working?

Comment: Design is messed up actually. Like navigation bar contents are messed up and responsiveness not working as expected. Buttons are mixed with each other like on top of each other & all

Comment: Tricky one to answer based on this information. My first thought is JavaScript. Are you using any kind of ES5/ES6 Javascript without transpiling it (like babel or webpack)? If there are a while since the iPhone is upgraded, newer javascript things are not working properly

Comment: FYI: you always need the <meta viewport...>

Comment: Useful. But I do not know what should I do. Should I get a hands-on with iPhone4S and then move towards a solution or what?

Comment: Unless you have some way of emulating iPhone 4s (expensive with professional tools) I would suggest to ask your client to activate debugging mode on their phone and send you the errors (of there are any). 
https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798